# Is it possible to filter the list of databases in the Object Explorer of the SSMS?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I know how to filter the list of tables - using the filter icon. However, this icon is disabled when the Databases node is selected.

Still, I am wondering whether it is possible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is now possible if you are using SQL Server Management Studio 2016. You can filter databases by Name, Owner and Creation Date.

I'm using SSMS build number 13.0.15900.1 - you can download a stand-alone version from Microsoft or just use this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx

Comment: Note that this feature is does not work on SQL Server *Express* servers.  That's my experience in SSMS 18.

Answer (score -1):

No, it is not possible to filter this list within SSMS.  My recommendation is to write a simple query reaching out to the system catalog view, `sys.databases`.

```
select name
from sys.databases
where name like '%<Your Search String>%';
```

Or some variation of that query, depending on what information you're looking to pull (I assumed only `name`, as the Object Explorer would provide you).

Comment: Unfortunately, my purpose is different. I just want less clutter in my Object Explorer.

Comment: Actually, it is possible to filter using the new SSMS version. Check this out: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlreleaseservices/announcing-sql-server-management-studio-16-3-august-2016-release/

Answer (score -1):

I use SSMS 18 and yes, I can filter the list of databases. My first step every morning is to filter to show only databases with the DEV suffix. Also, the above answer omits the ability to filter by schema. which can be pretty helpful if your team has the habit of compartmentalizing.
[image: Right-click for context menu to filter the database list.]
[image: Selecting the filter for the database list]

Comment: This answer could be improved by giving more detail and making it clear to which other answer you refer.